# bind multidimensional array with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a dynamic table on my front end side, and at the end i need to know what was inserted on each cell of my table since it is editable, so i did this on my html:

```
 <table class="table table-responsive">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row,idx1) in tableRows" :class="{headerRowDefault: checkHeader(idx1)}">
        <td class="table-success" v-for="(col,idx2) in tableCols"><input v-model="items[idx1][idx2]" type="text" class="borderTbl" value="HEY"/></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

as you guys can see. i set inside the input a v-model with items[idx1][idx2] so i can pass the value to that line and columns, it is not working like this, i don't know how to set it.

This is my javascript:

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      table: {
        rows: 1,
        cols: 1,
        key: 'Table',
        tableStyle: 1,
        caption: '',
        colx: []
      },
      hasHeader: true,
      hasCaption: true,
      insert: 1,
      idx2: 1,
      items: []
    }
  },
```

computed: {

```
tableStyles () {
  return this.$store.getters.getTableStyles
},
tableRows () {
  return parseInt(this.table.rows)
},
tableCols () {
  return parseInt(this.table.cols)
}
```

**expected items array:**

```
items:[
   ["john","Micheal"]
   ["john","Micheal"]
   ["john","Micheal"]
   ["john","Micheal"]
]
```

Comment: You need to provide html template for us to understand the problem

Comment: hehe i had it, strange it didn't place it

Comment: Where are you getting tableCols or tableRows?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 3):

So, I think you're not pointing your models correctly.

Template:

```
<tr v-for="(row, idx1) in items">
    <td class="table-success" v-for="(col, idx2) in row">
        <input v-model="items[idx1][idx2]" type="text" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Script:

```
data () {
  return {
    items:[
     ["john","Micheal"],
     ["john","Micheal"],
     ["john","Micheal"],
     ["john","Micheal"]
    ];
  };
}
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytk0e7kb/) of it

Comment: what did you change?

Comment: I just changed `v-for` in your `tr` and `td`. You should be looking into items, and loop through accordingly. Now that you've added more things to your question, I think computed properties aren't needed in this case. Please let me know if my answer is correct or if you were needing something different

Comment: i get a vue.esm.js:566 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Works ok for me. Can you check this way? I have updated the code above with a fiddle

Comment: well, when i add one more row ore one more column it adds the column for the first, but i can't add more rows dynamicly

Comment: That wasn't asked in the question though. Updated fiddle - I guess that will answer all your problems. When you think its correct, please approve & upvote the answer so that others may get help from it in the future

Comment: i aprove after this, my question is related to the error binding that issue is part of it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153352/discussion-between-nafiul-islam-and-filipe-costa).