# How can i use an multidimensional array for the v-model in Vue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

I want to generate an attribute variation for an online shop based on attribute values checked by user.

The problem is that i don't know how access the values of attributes from the v-model and what type of data must be the v-model?

I'm stuck here.Below is my code.

Thank you!

```
<div v-for="(attribute, index) in attributes">
    <p>{{ attribute.name }}</p>
    <div v-for="(attributevalue,indexval) in attribute.attribute_values">
        <input v-model="attributes[index][indexval]"  :value="attributevalue.id">
        <label>{{ attributevalue.name }}</label>
    </div>
</div>
<p>Generate</p>

export default {
   props:{
     attributes:{
      type:Array
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977778/bind-multidimensional-array-with-vuejs

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing `v-model` with `value`.

Comment: if i use that example i can't get the value (attributevalue.id) in the v-model, i get true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind 'id' to input then, this is what you should do -

```
<input type="text" v-model="attributevalue.id" >
```

This `attributes[index][indexval]` won't be needed as you have a nested for loop which does exactly the same. Hence, you can use directly `attributevalue` to access its properties in v-model.

A note about v-model:

It is a two way binding mechanism in vue and it will accept any type of value you want to pass to your underlying component as long as your component supports the type. In this case, input with type text accepts string/numeric values.

[v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) internally uses different properties and emits different events for different input elements:

- text and textarea elements use value property and input event;
- checkboxes and radiobuttons use checked property and change event;
- select fields use value as a prop and change as an event.

Comment: so, i need to use checkbox with change event to get the values?

Comment: @vlad You can use checkbox with either v-model or checkbox with value prop and change event. As explained earlier, v-model = value prop + change event in case of checkbox.

e.g. <input type="checkbox" :value="attributevalue.id" @change=""onAttributeChecked"> 

OR 

<input type="checkbox" v-model="attributevalue.id"> both can be used to achieve what you desire.

Comment: if i use <input type="checkbox" v-model="attributevalue.id"> all the checkboxex are check on reload. And how can i get the values from the v-model? Thanks!

Comment: Two way binding [v-model] automatically stores the changed result in the variable that is assigned as v-model. Hence, if you check or uncheck a checkbox, the corresponding value will automatically reflect in attributes array at [index][indexval].id.